# display Facebook page posts with it's image in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need some help please?
I developed an app that view the last 20 Facebook page feeds (posts with image if exists) i use the graph
(https://graph.facebook.com/229161663845327/feed?access_token=266494063684850|799f6a5b3246ceeecae7e95af945da24&limit=20) but it give me a result of text post without it's image how can i display & get both text and image for each post without making Facebook login in the app

Comment: try this "https://graph.facebook.com/229161663845327/feed?access_token=266494063684850|799f6a5b3246ceeecae7e95af945da24&limit=20&fields=full_picture"  add &fields=full_picture to your link

Comment: when add this part the result is just the photos without the text  like this:"data": [  {
         "full_picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtf1/v/t1.0-0/p480x480/13567371_1059579250803560_3293009082461222556njpg?",
         "id": "229161663845327_1059580214136797"  }

Comment: @sunilsunny Hi, do you have idea on publish a post from our app to facebook WorkPlace Page ?

Answer (score 2):

i finally solve this problem ,thanks to @sunil sunny your comment it's helpful.
i use this api " https://graph.facebook.com/229161663845327/feed?fields=full_picture,id,story,created_time,message&access_token=266494063684850|799f6a5b3246ceeecae7e95af945da24&limit=20 "

Comment: Is this done without 'login with facebook' functionality in android app? can you plz highlight the steps you did and share some links in comments.
i want to read my page data and show in android app without login with facebook.

Answer (score 2):

ya thanks to @sunil sunny , I solve this problem and it worked correctly without need of facebook login in your app,
Follow these step :

1- In facebook developer site, create new project and take the access_token to use in next step 
go to [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/) and  click 'Graph API Explorer' button 
[image]
2- make a request to this link using volley or http request or what you prefered to this link

```
String FACEBOOKURL="https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR Facebook PageID/feed?"
        +"fields=id,story,created_time,message,full_picture&access_token=/* put your access token that you take from step 1*/&limit=15"
```

[YOUR Facebook PageID](https://findmyfbid.com/)

3- the data retrieve from request as string can converted like this

```
   JSONObject dataObj = null;
            Log.i("// url", URL.FACEBOOKURL);
            try {
                String story = "";
                String message = "";
                String created_time = "";
                String image = "";
                String id = "";
                dataObj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jdata = dataObj.getJSONArray("data");
                JSONObject jpaging = dataObj.getJSONObject("paging");
                final String previous = jpaging.getString("previous");
                final String next = jpaging.getString("next");
                for (int i = 0; i < jdata.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jdata.getJSONObject(i);
                    try {
                        message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                        story = "";
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        story = jsonObject.getString("story");

                        Log.i("//story", story);
                    }
                    created_time = jsonObject.getString("created_time");
                    try {
                        image = jsonObject.getString("full_picture");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        image = "";
                    }
                    id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    String[] parts = id.split("_");
                    String pageId = parts[0];
                    final String postId = parts[1];
                    Log.i("---//message", postId);
                    Log.i("---//image", image);
                    fbDataList.add(new FbData(postId, message, story, created_time, image));
```

i make try catch because in each row of output data, it's changing such as full_picture its return when your post have image only and "story","message" one of them return, you can run the link in browser and see the output json and use it as you want

4- Finally you can put the output list to recyclerView

I hope this will be helpful :)

Comment: What is `response`? Please elaborate